# There's not enough memory to complete this operation.Please try again later when there may be more memory available error in excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, sql-server-data-tools

I have SQL Analysis server with 5 cubes.when we access cubes in excel at a time in 4 systems getting below error.

```
We could not get data from an external data source.please try again later.
if the problem persists.please contact the administrator for the external 
data source.Here is the error message that was returned from the Analysis 
Server named
There is not enough memory to complete this operation.please try again later 
when there may be more memory available.
```

Comment: What is your question here? The error is very very clear.

Comment: @Larnu I want to know the actual reason for this error and what are the steps should be taken to resolve above issue..

Comment: The reason is there isn't enough memory to simultaneously hold all the data you are trying to process

Comment: Like @Larnu said, error cannot be any clearer. It indicates that your data size is too large. Try and reducing number of rows returned by your query (maybe to top 100) just to check that you are able to get data into Excel. If that works.. well maybe your can divide the results of your query into smaller chunks when importing to Excel

Comment: If you're using a 32bit version of Excel that could be a hindrance. It has a lot less addressable RAM that the 64 bit version. Otherwise, if your OS is running out of memory, maybe it's time to upgrade. But, if you really are getting a 4GB, or similar/larger dataset, being returned perhaps you need to think about if you really *need* all that data.#

Comment: @larnu currently we are using 32bit version excel.what if we get more than 4GB data.

Comment: Excel 32bit can only address 2GB of RAM. If you have 4GB of data, you're way over your limit on addressable memory. But why would ever want a 4GB Excel file?!

Comment: No I am just asking about 4GB Excel file.

Comment: @Larnu we are getting this issue in all systems.

Comment: Well, yes. 32bit Excel will never be able to open a 4GB Excel file/

Comment: @larnu in my case data is less than 2GB and getting this error in all systems if we access cubes simultaneously.

Comment: @larnu what I have to do to resolve this issue.

Comment: Sounds like your SQL Server is running out of memory then. How much RAM does your SQL Server host have? What services are running on the Host? What limit do those services have in regards to memory?

Comment: @Larnu 32GB Ram,actually I have limited information about server now .

Comment: I'd suggest talking to your DBA then, @saij . If you can't answer those questions, there's little we can do to help you.

Comment: @larnu Right now I am unable to talk to DBA. Is there any problem with 32GB RAM

Comment: There were other questions in the comment @saij .